# Split list by one property and sort ascending nested list<T> by property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class:

```
class SimpleDevice 
{
    public string IMEI {get;set;}
    public long Timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

And a method to generate a List for testing purposes:

```
private static List<SimpleDevice> GenerateListOfDevices() 
{
    return new List<SimpleDevice>()
    {
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "bbbbb", Timestamp = 33 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "bbbbb", Timestamp = 45 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "aaaaa", Timestamp = 36 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "aaaaa", Timestamp = 37 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "aaaaa", Timestamp = 35 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "bbbbb", Timestamp = 34 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "aaaaa", Timestamp = 39 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "aaaaa", Timestamp = 38 },
        new SimpleDevice { IMEI = "bbbbb", Timestamp = 35 }
    };
}
```

I want to split the `List<SimpleDevice>` into `List<List<SimpleDevice>>` where the nested lists are grouped by the `IMEI`.

I then want to order the internal lists by their `Timestamp`, so I have a sequential output for each list.

Here's my `LINQ` statement:

```
private static List<List<SimpleDevice>> SplitAndSort (List<SimpleDevice> devices)
{
    return devices
            .Select(x => x)
            .GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
            .Select(x => x.Select(y => y).ToList())
            .OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => y.Timestamp))
            .ToList();
}
```

Which is throwing the following exception:

> Innermost exception     System.ArgumentException : At least one object must implement IComparable

Which is occuring in the `OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => y.Timestamp))`.

I had a Google and found that the type being `OrderedBy` on must implement `IComparable`, which the type `long` does:

`public struct Int64 : IComparable, IComparable<Int64>, ...`

Changing the internal `x => x.Select(...` inside my `OrderBy` to `x => x.Min(...` allowed me to compile and run my code, but the internal lists weren't ordered by their `Timestamp`, although the splitting worked:

```
IMEI: bbbbb, Timestamp: 33
IMEI: bbbbb, Timestamp: 45
IMEI: bbbbb, Timestamp: 34
IMEI: bbbbb, Timestamp: 35
IMEI: aaaaa, Timestamp: 36
IMEI: aaaaa, Timestamp: 37
IMEI: aaaaa, Timestamp: 35
IMEI: aaaaa, Timestamp: 39
IMEI: aaaaa, Timestamp: 38
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing when trying to order the internal lists in ascending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is a little bit messed up.
You've put the `OrderBy` in the wrong place - It works on the outer list instead of the internals. hence, the exception.

Do the ordering in the time you are selecting (generating) the nested lists:

```
private static List<List<SimpleDevice>> SplitAndSort(List<SimpleDevice> devices)
{
    return devices
                .GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
                .Select(g => g.Select(y => y).OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList())
                .ToList();
}
```

Note, that you take out the `.Select(y=>y)`, `OrderBy` is enough. (i didn't delete in above)

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you want:

```
private static List<List<SimpleDevice>> SplitAndSort (List<SimpleDevice> devices)
{
    return devices
            .GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
            .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y=> y.TimeStamp).ToList())
            .ToList();
}
```

Let me walk you through it:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
```

1. Group your list by IMEI.You now have an object of the type: IEnumerable<IGrouping<SimpleDevice>>, you just need the ToLists to make the type match.

```
.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y=> y.TimeStamp).ToList())
```

2. Within each group, order by the timestamp, and then call ToList() to give you your inner List. At this point you have an object of type IEnumerable<List<SimpleDevice>>

   .ToList();
3. Finally the last ToList will give you your return type of List<List<SimpleDevice>>

Answer (score 2):

Well let me try to walk you throw this.

First you make sure that the list is `ordered by` `Timestamp` so you know now that the list order is correct and then you do `GroupBy` and .`Select(x => x.Select(y => y).ToList())` which will give you `List<List<SimpleDevice>>`

```
    List<List<SimpleDevice>> test =  devices
        .OrderBy(x=> x.Timestamp)
        .GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
        .Select(x => x.Select(y => y).ToList())
        .ToList();
```

And here is the result

```
bbbbb 33
bbbbb 34
bbbbb 35
bbbbb 45
aaaaa 35
aaaaa 36
aaaaa 37
aaaaa 38
aaaaa 39
```

Answer (score 0):

You second select generates list of list. Order by also selects a list as compared value, which doesn't implement `IComparable`. If you add .FirstOrDefault`()` or alike it would work.

```
devices
   .GroupBy(x => x.IMEI)
   .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Timestamp).ToList()) // <- order inner list here
   //.OrderBy(x => x.Select(y => y.Timestamp)) // you don't need this line then
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't order the Timestamps, it has the same output as the sample in the OP.